# Simultaneously read from one file and write to another

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read bytes from a file, process them, and then write the process's output out to another file. Since the reading/writing is the bottleneck (the processing is quick) I should be able to almost double the speed (if the files are on different drives) by simultaneously reading and writing.

I can do this with inter-process-communication, but that seems like overkill. Is there a *simple* way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want the following:

1. read chunk
2. process it
3. start writing output
4. go to 1 while writing

**EDIT 2**

@downvoters Care to explain why? Is it *that* obvious what dasblinkenlight wrote that it's not even worthy of a question? I doubt I'm the *only* one who didn't know that.

Comment: If you have streams open for each file you can read from one stream and write to the other however you like.

Comment: @David Which is not simultaneous. I want to double that speed.

Comment: Since I/O is probably the bottleneck indeed, reading and writing as you go will be doing it in parallel anyway, as long as you do it in reasonably-sized chunks. The operating system will perform I/O in parallel for you.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are you saying that `Read` and `Write` won't block? How would that work?

Comment: OS will quickly figure out that you are reading sequentially, and use read-ahead to prefetch the next few blocks. By the time your program is done writing and is ready for some reading again, the data is already in the buffer, so OS will serve it to your program. In the time your program spends waiting for the write to finish, the OS will prefectch some more data, so the cycle will continue with virtually no wait on the reading side.

Comment: Why would they "block"?  If you have streams to two separate files, why would they interfere with each other?  You could do multi-threading and have one thread do the reading and another do the writing.  Putting the data in a buffer in between, but you'd have to worry about sync issues.  You'd probably end up executing faster by just reading and writing in the same process and letting the OS and hardware worry about buffering and running the hardware read/writes in parallel.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's good news. I didn't know that. You can transform your comment into an answer. And if you have any source for this that would be nice too. If not, I'll see your high rep as source enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should be able to almost double the speed by simultaneously reading and writing.

Unless you read the whole file in memory at once, doubling the speed is unlikely, because OS optimizes reading latency through [readahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readahead).

OS applies the principle of locality of reference: it quickly figures out that your program is reading sequentially, and uses read-ahead to prefetch the next few blocks. By the time your program is done writing and is ready for some reading again, the data is already in the buffer, so OS will serve it to your program. In the time your program spends waiting for the write to finish, the OS will prefectch some more data, so the cycle will continue with virtually no wait on the reading side.

As a matter of experiment you could try making your own program use [asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) by employing [`ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`WriteAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158629(v=vs.110).aspx) APIs. The process would go as follows:

1. Before entering the loop, set `Task pendingWrite = null`
2. Start the read with `ReadAsync` and `await` its completion
3. If no additional data is available, exit the loop (step 8)
4. Process the data as needed
5. See if there is a pending write task. If there is, `await` its completion
6. Initiate the next write with `WriteAsync`, and assign the task to `pendingWrite`
7. Go back to step 2
8. `await` completion of `pendingWrite` task from the last cycle.

Comment: Your algorithm in your edit seems to block. Step 2 will only finish when the chunk's writing is done, and step 3 will finish when the chunk's reading is done. (Because of the `await`s). Or were you trying to show how the OS will take care of it? Or did I misunderstand your algorithm? (Feel free to ignore this comment. Your main answer is all I really need now.) All we would gain by the Async's here is that the UI would still work.

Comment: @ispiro You're right, I should move awaiting for the previous write to complete to after the read is processed. This way the prior write and the current read will be active at the same time (i.e. pending write will proceed while you are awaiting the next read). I expect this change to produce no measurable change, though.